# python.exe file missing?

Tags: python

Okay, so about 6 months ago a guy built a program for my company using python. The program ran fine, but now all of a sudden, it doesn't work. The error message says it can't find python/python.exe. I'm just trying to figure out if this is a file that came with the python installation, or if this is something that was built by the programmer. Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: The logical followup question: what's changed on the computer(s) to cause it to stop working? My assumption is something broke the PATH variable to no longer point to C:\program files\PythonVCurrent\

Comment: This is not a programming question so it's possibly off-topic. It's also too localized, and doesn't contain enough info to answer, so it's not a real question.

Comment: A similar thing happened to me too. I have no idea what happened, but in the middle of writing my django application in JetBrains' PyCharm it started complaining about invalid interpreter. Somehow python.exe has disappeared from my disk without me even opening the folder...

Comment: Same problem as @varesa, My solution : Avast put my python.exe file in quarantine...need to go in the chest to add an exception for this file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python.exe is a compiler-cum-interpreter file that comes with Python Implementation Package. It runs the code written using the python language. You can't run python code until this is installed on your system. I suggest you go and download Python implementation from [HERE](http://www.python.org/getit/) for your OS and then try running the program you were doing earlier.